# Awk - count similar words between lines

Tags: bash, awk

I have text manipulation problem that I am not able to solve myself, hence I need help from smarter people.
My dummy file example looks like this:

```
Winter    Sally    Additional_text
Winter    Sally    Additional_text
Winter    Nicole    Additional_text  
Spring    Lucy    Additional_text
Spring    Lucy    Additional_text
Spring    Caroline    Additional_text
Spring    Caroline    Additional_text
Summer    Emma    Additional_text
Autumn    Rita    Additional_text
Autumn    Rita    Additional_text
Autumn    Cristina     Additional_text
Autumn    Lucy's_sister     Additional_text
Autumn    Lucy's_sister     Additional_text
```

I want to:
For every first column item count how many different names there are in the second column. But I have to count only those names that: 1) Occur at least twice AND 2) There are at least two different names (they both occur at least twice).
For the output like this:

```
Time    Counts 
Spring    2
Autumn    2
```

Output explanation:
In `Winter` there are two different names, but `Nicole` occurs only once - `winter` is not reported;
In `Spring` there are at least two different names AND each of them occur at least twice - reported how many different names there are in `Spring`;
In `Summer` only one name - `Summer` is not reported;
In `Autumn` three different names, but only two of them occur at least twice - reported counts only for `Rita` and `Lucy's_sister`.

**Edit**
My solution in awk and bash:

```
cut -d " " -f 1 FILE | sort -u > names
for i in $(cat names)
do 
   grep ^$i FILE | 
   awk '{print $2}' | 
   sort | 
   uniq -c | 
   awk -v VAR="$i" '($1>=2) {print VAR}' | 
   sort | 
   uniq -c | 
   awk '($1>=2) {print $2"\t"$1}' 
done
```

It's way too clumsy and repetitive, so I want to know more simple way of doing this.

Comment: And what have you tried yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is awk command that should work for you:

```
awk '{sums[$1"~"$2]++} END {for (a in sums) {split(a, b, "~"); if (sums[a]>1) suma[b[1]]++;}
      for (k in suma) if (suma[k]>1) print k, suma[k]}' inFile
```

Comment: How does `(sums[a]>1)` and `(suma[k]>1)` work? (What `1` means?)

Comment: `>1` in both cases are there to satisfy the requirement of count=2 as per your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{kc[$1 "-" $2]++ } 
     END { for (k in kc) { if (kc[k]>=2) {f[gensub("-.*","","g",k)]++}}
           for (kk in f) { if (f[kk]>=2 ) {print kk, f[kk]}}}' INPUTFILE
```

Will work for you. First it counts the number of "`FIRSTCOL-SECONDCOL`" occurrences in an array. Then at the end of file for every occurrence checks the number of occurrences and if it's greater than one, stores the `FIRSTCOL` in another array (as key) and adds one to its value. Then prints every `FIRSTVAL` and its value if it's greater than one. I'm leaving the header to you.

***Note***: it will fail if there's any '`-`' in the first column.

Comment: If you use [`SUBSEP`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multi_002ddimensional.html), you won't have that problem..

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f ./script.awk file
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    OFS="\t"
}
{
    a[$1][ b[$1,$2]++ ]++
}
END {
    print "Time", "Counts";
    for (i in a) {
        for (j in a[i]) {
            if (j >= 1 && a[i][j] >= 2) {
                print i, a[i][j]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk '{ a[$1][ b[$1,$2]++ ]++ } END { print "Time", "Counts"; for (i in a) for (j in a[i]) if (j >= 1 && a[i][j] >= 2) print i, a[i][j] }' OFS="\t" file
```

Results:

```
Time    Counts
Autumn  2
Spring  2
```